# EF Core 3.1 - Add Tag to IIncludableQueryable without changing type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

**TL;DR** - I need a way in EF core 3.1.4 to add a tag to an IIncludableQueryable object, and still keeping it as an IIncludableQueryable instead of changing the type to IQueryable (the return type of TagWith function)

A while ago I created a piece of code to add table hints to EF Core's queries, using tags and interceptors. At the time, I only added the ability to add the hints on the "main" entity and on the first level of included entities (i.e. those from the "Include" method but not "ThenInclude" methods) using extension methods. Now I want to be able to add hints to the "ThenInclude"ed entities, and be able to chain them.

E.g. if my query is

```
context.Games.Include(g => g.Events)
             .ThenInclude(e => e.Team)
             .ThenInclude(t => t.Players)
             .Where(...)
```

right now I can only add hints to Games (the main entity) and Events (the first level of include) tables, but not for Teams or Players. I want to be able to add hints to all of them.

This is the relevant code:

```
public static class QueryHintsExtensions
{
    private const string Tag = "Use hint:";

    public static IQueryable<T> AddHint<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, DbContext context, QueryHintsTypes hint, string optionalParameter = "")
    {
        var tableName = GetTableName(typeof(T), context);
        return source.AddTag(hint, tableName, optionalParameter);
    }

    public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> IncludeWithHint<TEntity, TProperty>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath, DbContext context, QueryHintsTypes hint, string optionalParameter = "") where TEntity : class
    {
        var tableName = GetTableName(typeof(TProperty), context);
        return source.AddTag(hint, tableName, optionalParameter).Include(navigationPropertyPath);
    }

    private static IQueryable<T> AddTag<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, QueryHintsTypes hint, string tableName, string optionalParameter = "")
    {
        return source.TagWith($"{Tag} {tableName},{hint},{optionalParameter}");
    }

    private static string GetTableName(Type ingestionModelType, DbContext context)
    {
        if (ingestionModelType.IsGenericType)
            ingestionModelType = ingestionModelType.GenericTypeArguments.Single();

        var model = context.Model;
        var entityType = model.FindEntityType(ingestionModelType);
        return entityType.GetTableName();
    }

    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder AddQueryHints(this DbContextOptionsBuilder builder) =>
        builder.AddInterceptors(new QueryHintInterceptor(Tag));
}
```

To get back to the example, in order to add forceseek to Games and Events tables, I would do this:

```
context.Games.AddHint(c, QueryHintsTypes.Forceseek)
             .IncludeWithHint(g => g.Events, c, QueryHintsTypes.Forceseek)
             .ThenInclude(e => e.Team)
             .ThenInclude(t => t.Players)
             .Where(...)
```

Now I also want to be able to do this:

```
context.Games.AddHint(c, QueryHintsTypes.Forceseek)
             .IncludeWithHint(g => g.Events, c, QueryHintsTypes.Forceseek)
             .ThenIncludeWithHint(e => e.Team, c, QueryHintsTypes.Forceseek)
             .ThenIncludeWithHint(t => t.Players, c, QueryHintsTypes.Forceseek)
             .Where(...)`
```

I can add the ability to do just one "ThenIncludeWithHint" by doing this:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> ThenIncludeWithHint<TEntity, TPrevious, TProperty>(this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPrevious> source, Expression<Func<TPrevious, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath, DbContext context, QueryHintsTypes hint, string optionalParameter = "") where TEntity : class
    {
        var tableName = GetTableName(typeof(TProperty), context);
        return source.ThenInclude(navigationPropertyPath).AddTag(hint, tableName, optionalParameter);
    }
```

But I would like to be able to chain "ThenIncludeWithHint", and for that I need to somehow be able to return an IIncludableQueryable from that method.

Is there any way to accomplish this?